# How to optimize mysql join query, Not using join

Tags: mysql, join, query-optimization

I am trying to optimize the below query it yields me the following result

```
EXPLAIN UPDATE table1 a
JOIN table2 b
    ON a.id=b.ref_id
SET a.value=b.value;
```

When i try to explain the query, I get the following result.

```
ID  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key         key_len ref         rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE          b       ALL     idx_ref_id                                      10785   
1   SIMPLE          a       ref     idx_id          idx_id      4       b.ref_id    24
```

As far as i understand query is using only one index i.e idx_id and not idx_ref_id.

**Edit:**

Here is the table structure.

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE table1;

CREATE TABLE table_1 (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `companyname` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `value` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `sve_value` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  KEY `idx_id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

SHOW CREATE TABLE table2;

CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `suggested_value_enrichement` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tags` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ref_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  KEY `idx_ref_id` (`ref_id`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Please help me, Also please correct me if am wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: why would you optimize this??

Comment: @zeljka it's more than 15 minutes

Comment: its impossible, you have only 10785 rows, show me your table data types, and are you doing this only one time, or you need to do it often?

Comment: you shouldn't do this often, just one time.. and set through code to update this column

Comment: @Zeljka those rows are expected.. Also because of `ALL` for table b MySQL most likely have to do `(10785  * 24) =  539250` records MySQL has to genererate and match for the join, that would explain the 15 minutes runtime

Comment: That's what shocked me. So I tried `show processlist` 20 active query was running on server but there was no lock on my table. After that logged in on Linux terminal and ran `free -g` out of 64 GB of ram 6 GB was still free.

Comment: ok, you can use group by to avoid duplicated join fields.. but generally something like this you can do just one time.. not doing it often

Comment: We need to see the table structures `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` for every table involved in the question..

Comment: @RaymondNijland I have updated the table structure.

Comment: i very much doubt that those are the correct table structures i suspect you manually changed them.. as `KEY idx_id (catid)` -> `catid` isn't a column in the table

Comment: No `PRIMARY KEY`?  No `UNIQUE`?  Are there 24 rows in table1 for each row in table2?  How big are the tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue with query was there were many process running on the server which choked the resources. Also there were many ideal connection to the database to precise around 150.

So by killing the process and terminating the ideal connection solved the issue.

Query execution finished within a minute.